# How to install libpostal or address parser on python or jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, parsing, jupyter-notebook, street-address

I am trying to use an address parser (international not us address). I found there is a parser named libpostal or address but I don't know how it work.

I am using Jupyter notebook and I trying to import this librarie but I have an error.

```
pip install address

from address import AddressParser, Address

ap = AddressParser()
```

Error code :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
from address import AddressParser, Address

File "c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\address_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .address import Address, AddressParser

File "c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\address\address.py", line 185
print "Unmatched token: ", token
^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Unmatched token: ", token)?

So I don't know why I have this error, there isn't a print function in this code.

Thank you for you're help.

Comment: It looks like the `address` module you're using was written for Python 2, and you're using Python 3. That suggests the `address` module is no longer maintained.

Comment: @larsks Do you know if there is a new version of this library ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that module.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.